# entering one value in asp form's field, will show the details in gridview

Tags: asp.net

There are four fields in my asp.net form namely Purchase Date, Category, Item Name and Item Code. If we enter a value in any of these fields, other three field information must display in a gridview.  Suppose, if we enter only the purchase date, the details corresponding to that date will display in gridview. I want the stored procedure as well as cs code.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: yes... but, am not sure, whether it is correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly and we suppose that you use SQL, then it should look something like this:

```
protected void YourEventThatStart(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
YourGrid.DataSource = GetDataTable("SELECT PurchaseDate, Category, ItemName, ItemCode FROM sometable WHERE PurchaseDate like '%" + Field1.Text + "%' and Category like '%" + Field2.Text + "%' and ItemName like '%" + Field3.Text + "%' and ItemCode like '%" + Field3.Text + "%'");
}

public DataTable GetDataTable(string query)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=;Initial Catalog=;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=;Password=);
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
            DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable();
            conn.Open();
            try
            {
                adapter.Fill(myDataTable);
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Dispose();
            }
            return myDataTable;
        }
```

If you don't use selectcommand more than once then you can remove `public DataTable GetDataTable(string query)` and use that code inside `YourEventThatStart` event.

Now all you need is just to execute that `YourEventThatStart` event whenever you need to populate your grid, on whatever event you want.